# How to accurately summate Clenshaw algorithm

Tags: c++, math

I have following code to summate Chebyshev expansion of a function using Clenshaw algorithm:

```
long double summate_chebyshev(long double x, long double* c, int count) {
    long double bn, bn_1 = 0, bn_2 = 0;
    for (int i = count - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        bn = c[i] + 2.0*x*bn_1 - bn_2;
        bn_2 = bn_1;
        bn_1 = bn;

    }
    bn = 2.0l*c[0] + 2.0*x*bn_1 - bn_2;
    return (bn - bn_2)/2.0l;
}
```

I gives me pretty nice precision but Chebyshev polynomial coefficients tend to converge to 0 pretty quickly (c[17] is already 4.34e-20 < LDBL_EPS, so it ignores it). I wish to increase accuracy of summation and add more terms that is quite small but make the difference together. Is there any way to achieve this (improved versions of Clenshaw summation or any other method to evaluate Chebyshev polynomials accurately)?

Comment: Very broad question (or ag least asking for 3rd party resources). Maybe get rid of _floating point_ datatypes, and look for something hand rolled, with a predefined and predictable precision ratio.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Creating arbitrary precision arithmetic will require more modules to add to the project and I don't want to do that. If there will be a way to increase accuracy without adding more modules I will do it, if not I will leave it as it is

Comment: I am afraid there's no way to increase accuracy based on floating point types as I mentioned (may be yo got that wrong).